# AJAX does not redirect to a webpage after file uploading - POST method

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, file-upload

I am currently trying to develop a Java web application optimized for Google Chrome (4 and higher).

I would like the user to be able to select several files, upload them to a server (using a form displayed in a webpage called uploadForm) and when the uploading has finished, to be automatically redirected to another webpage (called upload).

Therefore, I have created a JSP file (**uploadForm.jsp**) where an upload form has been defined. I have also implemented the file uploading process using the XMLHttpRequest object (It is part of the Software Specifications. I have no other choice)

```
<body>
    <form id="file_form" action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file_input[]" id="file_select" multiple webkitdirectory=""/> 
        <button type="submit" id="upload_button" >Upload</button>
    </form> 
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

        // Get the form
        var form = document.getElementById("file_form");

        // Get the file selecter
        var fileSelect = document.getElementById("file_select");

        // Get the button which allows to upload the documents
        var uploadButton = document.getElementById("upload_button");

        // Set up the request
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // Create a new FormData object
        var formData = new FormData();

        form.onsubmit = function(event){

            // Prevent the form to be submitted. We want to write our 
            // own submission protocol
            event.preventDefault();

            // Update the button status during the uploading
            uploadButton.innerHTML = 'Uploading...';

            // Get the selected files from the input
            var files = fileSelect.files;

            // Loop through each of the selected files
            for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){

                // The file contained in the file list
                var file = files[i];

                // Add the file to the request
                formData.append('file_input[]',file,file.name);

                xhr.open('POST','upload',true);  

                // Send the data
                xhr.send(formData);                 
            }
        };

        // Set up a handler for when the request finishes
        xhr.onload = function(){

            if(xhr.status===200){

                // File uploaded
                uploadButton.innerHTML = 'Uploaded';
            }else{
                alert('An error occurred.File was not uploaded');
            }
        };

    </script>
```

When the upload has finished. The user is automatically redirected to another webpage called "upload" (**upload.jsp**) and referenced by a Servlet (**UploadServlet.java**):

**upload.jsp:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        Everything ok
    </body>
</html>
```

**UploadServlet.java:**

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/upload"})
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("I am in the servlet");

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/upload.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request,response);
 }
```

The selected files are correctly uploaded to the server. However, when the uploading has finished, the user is actually not redirected to the "upload" webpage. He remains in the "uploadForm" webpage and this is not what I expected.

Could you help me please ?
Thank you so much for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ajax calls will not cause a redirect (directly).  When you get your 200 ready state change back have the javascript do the redirect.  instead of having a forward in your servlet you may consider having it return information that the file was correctly uploaded and check that for validation...